# Add background image with Python script

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new to Blender. I've seen many similar questions online but none solved my issue.

I'm simply trying to add a background image to my render (in which there is a face) but, even if in the "preview" window I see the background, in the rendered image there is not. Here is my code:

````
import random
import os
import mathutils
import math 

# Set the number of renders to generate
num_renders = 2

# Get the active object and its first bone
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bone = obj.pose.bones["mainEye_H"]

# Set the initial bone location
initial_location = bone.location.copy()

# Set the camera location and rotation
camera = bpy.context.scene.camera
camera.location = (0.0000, -0.5702, 1.7050)
camera.rotation_euler = (1.5708, 0.0000, 0.0000)

# Add the background image to the camera
bg_img = bpy.data.images.load("C:/Users/user/Desktop/background_images/1.jpg")
bg_data = camera.data.background_images.new()
bg_data.image = bg_img
camera.data.show_background_images = True

# Loop over the number of renders
for i in range(num_renders):
    # Randomly move the bone along the X and Z axes while keeping Y fixed
    bone.location.x = initial_location.x + random.uniform(-0.17, 0.17)
    bone.location.z = initial_location.z + random.uniform(-0.17, 0.17)
    bone.location.y = 0.3

    # Update the pose to apply the new location
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().update()

    # Set the output path for the render
    output_path = os.path.join("C:/Users/user/Desktop/images_generation/", f"render_{i+1}.png")

    # Set the render settings
    bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 512
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 512
    bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = False

    # Render the image
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

    # Reset the bone location
    bone.location = initial_location

    # Update the pose to apply the reset location
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().update()```
````

Comment: Camera background image is an overlay. I don't think it is rendered.

Comment: So how can I solve this?

Comment: You can for instance use the compositor. But do you need to code all or can you manually prepare the scene for that?

Comment: You need to either add an image as background as a postprocess in the compositor workspace, making sure you render the background as transparent first, or use the image as a background using the camera output from the light path node in the world shading properties or use "Import image as plane" addon

Comment: @lemon it should be all coded since it will be automatized

Comment: so I imagin it will be applied to many blend files? may they include some compositing nodes already? and may the script turn transparent film without interfering with other things?

Comment: @lemon I import a human figure from Daz and then whit this script generate n renders of the same view but randomly moving a bone

Comment: Using import image as plane seems the simplest solution so far, thanks @Gorgious